# Finding solution to a differential equation given the initial condition

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given $dy/dx = 2y/(2x+1)$ and the initial condition $y(0)=e$ and $x>-1/2$, find the solution y.

I was able to separate the variables and integrate both sides respectively. I then tried to use the initial condition to find my Constant of integration but I get lost after that step. I don't know how i am supposed to isolate y from $ln(2y)$ on the left side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

${{dy}\over y}={{2dx}\over{2x+1}}$ implies that $ln(|y|)=ln(|2x+1|)+c$, you deduce that $y=A(2x+1)$ and $A=e$.

Comment: @Isham There is no square. Your integration is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I post a full solution

$$dy/dx = 2y/(2x+1)$$
$$\frac {y'}{y}=\frac 2 {2x+1}$$
$$(\ln(y))'=\frac 2 {2x+1}$$
$$\ln(y)=2\int \frac {dx} {2x+1}$$
$$\ln(y)=\ln(2x+1)+K$$
Take the exponential
$$y=e^{\ln(2x+1)+K}=Ke^{\ln(2x+1)}=K(e^{\ln(2x+1)})$$
$$y=K(2x+1)$$
$$y(0)=e \implies K=e$$
$$\boxed{y=e(2x+1)}$$

Note that
$$\int \frac {dy}{2y}=\frac 12 \ln|y|$$
And that
$$\int \frac {2dy}{y}=2\int \frac {dy}{y}=2 \ln|y|=\ln (y^2)$$
And more generaly for $\alpha$ constant:
$$\int \alpha f(x) dx=\alpha\int f(x)dx$$

Comment: By the chain rule, $(\ln(2x+1))' = \frac{2}{2x+1} $

Comment: @Dylan Thanks corrected...